# adjacency list construction

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm having problems understanding the final output of

```
for i in edgeList:
    adjacencyList[i[0]].append(i[0])
```

in the code below. I've tried printing out statements in every line to try and understand but am still confused.

```
    vertexList = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6"]
    edgeList = [(0,1), (0,2),(1,0), (1,3), (2,0), (2,4), (2,5), (3,1), (4,2), (4,6), (5,2), (6,4)]

    adjacencyList = [[] for vertex in vertexList]

    for i in edgeList:
        adjacencyList[i[0]].append(i[1])

    print(adjacencyList)

Output: [[1, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4, 5], [1], [2, 6], [2], [4]]
```

Is this considered a for loop occuring within a for loop because of the list comprehension? Appreciate if someone could spell out what is happening here. (this is related to BFS in graph theory)

Comment: It is not rewarding to understand the given code, since it is quite inferior: `vertexList` is practically useless, the code would not work for vertices not starting from zero, just its length is used (this woiuld be easier using `len()` instead of a list comprehension.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nice tool to visualize graph problems is graphviz, which comes with a `dot` command. First create `edgelist.dot` containing all the edges from your `edgeList` variable:

```
digraph G {
    0 -> 1
    0 -> 2
    1 -> 0
    1 -> 3
    2 -> 0
    2 -> 4
    2 -> 5
    3 -> 1
    4 -> 2
    4 -> 6
    5 -> 2
    6 -> 4
}
```

(there are shorter ways to write this that you can look up).
Then feed it through `dot`:

```
c:\srv\tmp> dot -Tsvg -o edgelist.svg edgelist.dot
```

and then open the created `edgelist.svg` file:

[image: graph created by graphviz]

The adjacency lists are the lists of nodes that can be reached from a particular node, e.g. for node `0` there are arrows to nodes `1` and `2`, thus `adjacencyList[0]`, i.e. the adjacency list for node `0` should be `[1, 2]`.

Similarly, the out-arrows from node `2` reaches nodes `0`, `4`, and `5`, so `adjacencyList[2]` should be `[0, 4, 5]`.

Manually going through each node in order, the adjacency list ends up with:

```
            [[1, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4, 5], [1], [2, 6], [2], [4]]
             ^       ^       ^          ^    ^       ^    ^
item/index:  0       1       2          3    4       5    6
```

In your code, this line:

```
adjacencyList = [[] for vertex in vertexList]
```

just creates `adjacencyList` as a list of empty lists (`[]`) with length equal to the number of vertexes.

Then this for loop:

```
for i in edgeList:
    adjacencyList[i[0]].append(i[0])
```

attempts to fill it in. To see what is wrong we can rewrite the for-loop so that it unpacks the edges in `edgeList`:

```
for (start, end) in edgeList:
    adjacencyList[start].append(..?..)
```

obviously the `..?..` should be `end` and not start:

```
for start, end in edgeList:
    adjacencyList[start].append(end)
```

Now you can see that the for-loop is doing what we did manually above, for each edge `(start, end)` it adds `end` to the adjacency list of `start`.

*Addendum:* Your code works well for cases where the vertexes (`0`, `1`, etc.) have the same values as the indexes in an array. While it is efficient it may not be pedagogically preferable (or maybe it is, I don't know ;-)  In any case, if we rename your vertices so that `0` becomes `"A"`, `1` becomes `"B"` etc., you'll need to use a different data structure for the adjacency list, e.g.:

```
from collections import defaultdict

edgeList = [("A", "B"),
            ("A", "C"),
            ("B","A"), ("B","D"),
            ("C","A"), ("C","E"), ("C","F"),
            ("D","B"),
            ("E","C"), ("E","G"),
            ("F","C"),
            ("G","E")]

adjacencyList = defaultdict(list)

for start, end in edgeList:
    adjacencyList[start].append(end)

print(sorted(adjacencyList.items()))
```

which prints:

```
[('A', ['B', 'C']), ('B', ['A', 'D']), ('C', ['A', 'E', 'F']), ('D', ['B']), ('E', ['C', 'G']), ('F', ['C']), ('G', ['E'])]
```

meaning the adjacency list for `'A'` is `['B', 'C']` etc.

it's possible (and perhaps beneficial for running time) to translate this version to the first version (especially in languages more static than Python).

Answer (score 2):

Your `adjacencyList` construction is wrong.

Replace
`adjacencyList[i[0]].append(i[0])`
with `adjacencyList[i[0]].append(i[1])`. I don't see any for loops inside another. Your time complexity is `O(n)`.

Purpose of the `adjacencyList` is to store all the adjacent nodes for a given node, In your case it is the index of the list.

After the change your output should be

> [[1, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4, 5], [1], [2, 6], [2], [4]]

From this you can interpret that 0 has 1 and 2 as neighbors. 2 has 0 and 3 neighbors, 3 has 0,4 and 5 as neighbors and so on.

Note that this approach fails if you have nodes like {2, 60, 1000, 4}. Better use a dictionary of nodes and a list of neighbors in that case.